# Convert grayscale image to numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a grayscale image here and I am trying to convert it to numpy array so I can utilise argwhere function to locate coordinates (x,y) of pixels with intensity of 255 (white).

So far I have the following:

```
photo = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select file", filetypes=(("png files", "*.png"), ("all files", "*.*")))
img = PIL.Image.open(photo).convert('L')
```

I have tried np.asarray(img) but it just returns:

```
[[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 ...
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]
```

At this stage I'm afraid I am stuck on what to do next, so any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is the image black in the corners?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grayscale image to NumPy array for Fourier transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14577007/grayscale-image-to-numpy-array-for-fourier-transform)

Comment: Try saving the data you get with `np.asarray` into a text file `numpy.savetxt` so that you can take a look at the entire data in that array. Also, according to the link I posted, `np.asarray(img)` should probably be `np.asarray(img.getdata())`. Good Luck!

Comment: Why have you removed your `import` statements? It makes your code hard to run.

Comment: The `np.asarray(img)`. in your question works for me. Print the rows in `np.asarray(img)` individually, there should be some non-black pixels (unless the image itself is all black, of course).

Comment: You can just use `np.array(img)` by the way.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Yes the image is pretty much all black as you can see here: https://i.imgur.com/8OAtWUx.png
And thank you to everyone else, I'll try all your suggestions :)

Comment: @MarkSetchell My bad, I didn't make it a habit to include the imports for the code snippet. But they are: 
import PIL
from PIL import Image
from tkinter import filedialog

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sounds like your code is probably working then! Numpy is only showing you the corners of the array because it's too big to print. Check `np.sum(np.asarray(img))` to see whether it's **all** zeroes.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Yes I realised that it is actually working after I saved it to text file according to Daniel F's suggestion. Thanks for your explanation :)

Comment: Glad to hear it!