# How to save an Image locally using PIL

Tags: python, image, path, save, python-imaging-library

I am making a program that builds a thumbnail based on user input, and I am running into problems actually saving the image. I am used to C++ where you can simply save the image, it seems that python does not support this.

This is my code right now:

```
def combine(self):
    img = Image.new("RGBA", (top.width,top.height+mid.height+mid.height),(255,255,255))
    img.paste(top, (0,0))
    img.paste(mid, (0,top.height))
    img.paste(bot, (0,top.height+mid.height))
    img.show()
    img.save("Thumbnail.png", "PNG")
```

The error that shows up when I run it is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "TextToThumbnail.py", line 4, in <module>
    class Thumbnail(object):
  File "TextToThumbnail.py", line 461, in Thumbnail
    img.save("Thumbnail.png", "PNG")
NameError: name 'img' is not defined
```

What is going on? Preferably I just want to be able to save the image locally, since this program will be running on multiple setups with different pathways to the program.

Comment: Do you need .img.fromArray.save?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452824/how-can-i-save-an-image-with-pil

Comment: Can you define what are top, mid and bot objects are ?

Comment: top mid and bot are all Images. The thing is, is that .show operates correctly, it only throws the error when I try to save it.