# changing format image PIL or openCV

Tags: python, image, opencv, python-imaging-library, scikit-image

I do not know the original format and I want how to use options to save my image like

- **mode** = 'RGB' or 'grayscaler' or 'RGBA'
- **number of bits** = 1 or 8 or 24 or 32 bits

How can I do that?

```
from PIL import Image
image = Image.open(path_my_image)
image.save(image, mode = 'RGBA', number_bits = 24)
```

Comment: Could you please be more specific about your problem?

Comment: hi @Sharky, i want to save image by mode like RGB or RGBA or grayscaler.
how i can do that ??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452824/how-can-i-save-an-image-with-pil