# it is easy to convert a jpg to a bmp on MacOS with OpenCV. is it possible to do the job with pillow?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

it is very easy to convert a jpg to a bmp on MacOS with OpenCV.

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('a.jpg',1)
cv2.imwrite('a.bmp',img)
```

I am curious if it possible to do the job with pillow?

here is the piece of code on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14472089/10253483)

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as numpy

img = Image.open("xhty23.jpg").convert('L')

im = numpy.array(img)
fft_mag = numpy.abs(numpy.fft.fftshift(numpy.fft.fft2(im)))

visual = numpy.log(fft_mag)
visual = (visual - visual.min()) / (visual.max() - visual.min())

result = Image.fromarray((visual * 255).astype(numpy.uint8))
result.save('out.bmp')
```

the file saved by above looks like

[image]

which is far from a bmp format of original image.

saving image as bmp encounters error.

> -------------------------------------------------------------------------- KeyError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         3 b = np.abs(np.fft.rfft2(a))
>         4 j = Image.fromarray(b)
>   ----> 5 j.save("a",".bmp")
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py in
>   save(self, fp, format, **params)    1956             save_handler =
>   SAVE_ALL[format.upper()]    1957         else:
>   -> 1958             save_handler = SAVE[format.upper()]    1959     1960         if open_fp:
>
> KeyError: '.BMP'

```
j.save("a.bmp")
```

gets this error

> -------------------------------------------------------------------------- KeyError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)
>   ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/BmpImagePlugin.py
>   in _save(im, fp, filename)
>       272     try:
>   --> 273         rawmode, bits, colors = SAVE[im.mode]
>       274     except KeyError:
>
> KeyError: 'F'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> OSError                                  Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         3 b = np.abs(np.fft.rfft2(a))
>         4 j = Image.fromarray(b)
>   ----> 5 j.save("a.bmp")
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py in
>   save(self, fp, format, **params)    1967     1968         try:
>   -> 1969             save_handler(self, fp, filename)    1970         finally:    1971             # do what we can to clean up
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/BmpImagePlugin.py
>   in _save(im, fp, filename)
>       273         rawmode, bits, colors = SAVE[im.mode]
>       274     except KeyError:
>   --> 275         raise IOError("cannot write mode %s as BMP" % im.mode)
>       276 
>       277     info = im.encoderinfo
>
> OSError: cannot write mode F as BMP

I already tried everything in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14472089/10253483), none of them works.

any ideas?

Comment: Try `j.save("a.bmp")`!

Answer (score 1):

You can do that more simply with **SIPS** - Apple's built-in *"Scriptable Image Processing System"* which has shipped with all versions of macOS/OSX since the year dot. No need to install any Python or PIL/Pillow packages.

Just in Terminal:

```
sips -s format bmp input.jpg --out output.bmp
```