# Save Numpy array graphs and images as images

Tags: python, database, image, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I cannot find a way to save my graphs and images. I have tried from

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.fromarray()
im.save("your_file.jpeg")
```

but doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

Please format your code correctly, it is important for readability and python is intend-sensitive. Also, there is already a post for this problem:

[How can I save an image with PIL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452824/how-can-i-save-an-image-with-pil)

Comment: i do add ''' speech marks but it never formats. How do i do it properly? Also, this answer isn;t saving my graphs