# PIL Text Rotating (discord.py)

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, discord.py

```
@client.command()
async def shit(ctx, *, response=None):
    if response == None:
        await ctx.send("What am I gonna write lol")
    response = response.replace("(", "")
    response = response.replace(")", "")
    txt = Image.new('L', (500, 50))
    img = Image.open("img/shit-empty.jpg")
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    w = txt.rotate(17.5, expand=1)

    font = ImageFont.truetype("Roboto-Bold.ttf", 50)
    # draw.text((x, y),"Sample Text",(r,g,b))
    draw.text((315, 845), f"{response}", font=font)
    img.paste(ImageOps.colorize(w, (0, 0, 0), (255,255,84)), (242,60), w)

    img.save('img/shit.jpg')

    await ctx.send(":poop: Eww")
    await ctx.send(file=discord.File("img/shit.jpg"))
```

So this is the code of one of my image editing commands. It works fine but it gives like this:
[image]

I want to rotate the text as it would match with the shoe rotation, how can i do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245447/how-do-i-draw-text-at-an-angle-using-pythons-pil

Comment: @SamMorgan no it didn't work

Comment: What exactly doesn't work. Show code. You need to create a Text object first, rotate that, then paste it into the picture.

Comment: @TinNguyen I updated the question, it didnt rotate but it sent the image. So its the same as in the image