# Draw text on an Image diagonally at random positions

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have figured out how to add text to an Image and this is how I have implemented it.

```
import docx
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageFont
from PIL import ImageDraw

img = Image.open("a.jpg")
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
font = ImageFont.truetype(<font-file>, <font-size>)
font = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", 16)
draw.text((x, y),"Sample Text",(r,g,b))
draw.text((0, 0),"Sample Text",(255,255,255),font=font)
img.save('C:\\Users\\John\\Desktop\\See\\sample-out.jpg')
```

From the [documentation (draw.text())](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.ImageDraw.text) i understand it takes position (xy) as the first argument.

How can I pass 3 variables (`firstplate, secondplate, thirdplate`) to the text argument and have them dispalyed randomly diagonally (like red) across the Image like below?

Am having great difficulty figuring out how to make the text diagonal, and add them in a loop all across the image.

[image: The Goal]

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? It seems like you are on the right track, you just need to define a function that takes in the 3 (or list of) strings.

Comment: @jtbandes, am mainly stuck trying to rotate the text to a diagonal position, I have a little edit to the question

Comment: You have this answer to rotate the text : https://stackoverflow.com/a/245892/10409093 . You can create three rotated images with text, then make a loop and use `random.choice` to pick randomly one of the three images to paste.

Comment: Thanks, am trying jtbandes  and Whole Brain's guide. Will update the question with the answer once I have it working